# Including the JAR in the same folder to maintain consistency

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, netbeans-7, include-path

I have the JAR files in Netbeans as follows:

[image]

However, when I check in the Properties section after right clicking on the Netbeans Project, my sqljdbc4.jar is some what different from the other JAR files, I mean it's path is different, since I added it afterwards as shown in the image below:

[image]

1) I have got a feeling that, since the path is different, I am not able to connect to SQL Server.

2) Also, when I would have to send the whole project to someone, this relative path won't work I believe. Is there a way, I can insert `sqljdbc4.jar` inside the `src/bundle_includes` folder just like the other ones? Please advise. I am using Netbeans 7.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that when you have added the `sqljdbc4.jar` it was on the desktop, so Netbeans linked it letting your source code compile, but this don't include the jar into your `src/bundle_includes`.

You should:

1. manually copy `sqljdbc4.jar` into `src/bundle_includes`
2. removing the `sqljdbc4.jar` with bad path from the Compile panel
3. click Add JAR/Folder and choose `src/bundle_includes/sqljdbc4.jar`

Comment: Thanks very much !! That did work and now I have all the JAR files under `src/bundle_included` folder.